# Getting the image src attribute to return multiple links to display the image as a jpeg?

Tags: javascript, image

I am attempting to return multiple URL's embedded in the picture field which are linked to posted pictures from a Facebook feed so that they will display as images and not just links. My issue is that I don't know how to implement the img src attribute in the response function. I have attempted to incorporate it into the node method highlighted below but it only attaches the elements to the link. Any help would be appreciated.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '**********',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.12'


  });
  FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/page_name/posts/?access_token=********', {
    fields: 'message,link,created_time,name,story, picture'
  }, function(response) {
    for (var l = response.data.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      var obj = response.data[i];
      var node = document.createElement("wall-post");
      //var node2 = document.createElement("wall-post-header");  
      var textNode = document.createTextNode('<img src=' + obj.picture + '/>');
      //var timeNode = document.createTextNode(obj.created_time);
      node.appendChild(textNode);
      //node2.appendChild(timeNode);
      node.style = ' display: inline-block;margin: 15px;margin-top: 30px; border-radius: px;overflow-y: hidden;box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);float:left;';
      //node2.style='height: 50px;overflow: hidden;background-color:#272727;color: white;line-height: 31px;padding: 9px;float: right;text-align: right;display: inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;font-size: 12px; line-height: 31px;padding: 9px;float: left;text-align: left;display: inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;width: 70%';
      document.body.appendChild(node);
      //document.body.appendChild(node2);
    }
  })
};


(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a text node, create and `Image` and set the `src` property.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = obj.picture;
```

Append the image as normal:

```
node.appendChild(image);
```

Here's a quick demo:

```js
function addImage() {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"
  
  const node = document.getElementById('x');
  node.appendChild(image);
}
```

```html
<h3>Demo for appending Images</h3>

<div id="x"></div>

<button onclick="addImage()">Add Image</button>
```